# How to increment the value of an object in an array of objects. Mongoose and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create something like an award system and I'm looking for the best option to do that.
Depending on which award was incremented I have to increase by one the value of it.
This is what my model looks like:

```
 const CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  awards: {
    "awardOne": 0,
    "awardTwo": 0,
    "awardThree": 0,
    "awardFour": 0
  },
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
})
```

Now what is the best way of incrementing by one for example awardOne.

```
exports.awardCard = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const awardOption = req.body.award; //Name of the award
  const card = Card.findById(id)

   if(!card){
        res.status(200).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Card not found"
   }

  card.update ... //This is where I don't know how to manage the update

  card.save()

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    card
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.awardCard = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const awardOption = req.body.award; //Name of the award
  const card = await Card.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":id}, { $inc: { [`awards.${awardOption}`]: 1 } }, {new: true});

   if(!card){
        res.status(200).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Card not found"
   }

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    card
  })
});
```